# ReactJS Object mapping, Undefined property, even though it's there

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to create a Stripe implementation plan with Cloud Firestore from Firebase and ReactJs and I am facing an issue that I can`t figure out. I have this object that I want to access its priceId

```
{
    "tax_code": null,
    "images": [],
    "name": "Premium Plan",
    "description": "4k + HDR + 5 Family Members",
    "active": true,
    "role": null,
    "metadata": {},
    "prices": {
        "priceId": "price_1LpD2rHO1lI6EMwl58lLNxRo",
        "product": "prod_MYJgCtqv3JyCPn",
        "metadata": {},
        "unit_amount": 15000,
        "transform_quantity": null,
        "interval_count": 1,
        "tiers_mode": null,
        "description": "150",
        "trial_period_days": null,
        "type": "recurring",
        "active": true,
        "tiers": null,
        "interval": "month",
        "tax_behavior": "unspecified",
        "currency": "dkk",
        "recurring": {
            "trial_period_days": null,
            "usage_type": "licensed",
            "interval_count": 1,
            "interval": "month",
            "aggregate_usage": null
        },
        "billing_scheme": "per_unit"
    }
}
```

That is how my code looks. First I am fetching the data from CloudFirestore and I create an object that has the price id within each product. Than in the return I am trying to map this object, and to get the priceId. For some reason that does not work. If I `console.log(productData?.prices?.priceId)` it shows me the priceId, but then it says undefined like you see in the picture below:
[image: undefined property].

I need the priceId so I make the loadCheckout work. Thank you for your help.

```
function PlanScreen() {
  const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);
  const user = useSelector(selectUser);

  //   console.log(products)
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  const fetchData = async () => {
    const q = query(collection(db, "products"), where("active", "==", true));
    const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);
    const products = {};
    const data = querySnapshot.forEach(async (productDoc) => {
      products[productDoc.id] = productDoc.data();
      const subQuery = query(
        collection(db, `products/${productDoc.id}/prices`)
      );
      const subQDetails = await getDocs(subQuery);
      subQDetails.docs.map((price) => {
        products[productDoc.id].prices = {
          priceId: price.id,
          ...price.data(),
        };
      });
    });
    setProducts(products);
  };

  const loadCheckout = async (priceId) => {
    const firstQ = collection(db, `customers/${user.uid}/checkout_sessions`);
    const secondQ = query(
      addDoc(firstQ, {
        price: priceId,
        success_url: window.location.origin,
        cancel_url: window.location.origin,
      })
    );

    onSnapshot(secondQ, async (snap) => {
      const { error, sessionId } = snap.data();

      if (error) {
        alert(`An error occured: ${error.message}`);
        console.log(error.message);
      }
      if (sessionId) {
        const stripe = await loadStripe(
          "pk_test_51LpCKmHO1lI6EMwlLvPQQSBZ2A6JTa6PmqXwLcYstnaf04qaG7CQYGW3DYWmrIL4QjzXfKQnDQaIeWSjrHyLx0fY000otcrJ7t"
        );
        stripe.redirectToCheckout({ sessionId });
      }
    });
  };

  return (
    <div className="planScreen">
      {Object.entries(products).map(([productId, productData]) => {
        console.log(productData);
        return (
          <div className="planScreen_plan" key={productId}>
            <div className="planScreen_info">
              <h5>{productData.name}</h5>
              <h6>{productData.description}</h6>
              <h6>{productData?.prices?.priceId}</h6>
            </div>

            <button onClick={() => loadCheckout(productData.prices.priceId)}>
              Subscribe
            </button>
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your call to `setProducts(products)` runs before any of the `await getDocs(subQuery)` has completed, because `forEach` is not an asynchronous operator.

You can either move the call to `setProducts(products)` into the callback (simplest), or use a `for of` loop (which *does* allow asynchronous callbacks in its body) to loop over the products.

#### Move the call to `setProducts` into the callback

```
const fetchData = async () => {
  const q = query(collection(db, "products"), where("active", "==", true));
  const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);
  const products = {};
  const data = querySnapshot.forEach(async (productDoc) => {
    products[productDoc.id] = productDoc.data();
    const subQuery = query(
      collection(db, `products/${productDoc.id}/prices`)
    );
    const subQDetails = await getDocs(subQuery);
    subQDetails.docs.map((price) => {
      products[productDoc.id].prices = {
        priceId: price.id,
        ...price.data(),
      };
    });
    setProducts(products); // 
  });
};
```

#### Use a `for of` loop

```
const fetchData = async () => {
  const q = query(collection(db, "products"), where("active", "==", true));
  const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);
  const products = {};
  const data = 
  for (var productDoc of querySnapshot.docs) { // 
    products[productDoc.id] = productDoc.data();
    const subQuery = query(
      collection(db, `products/${productDoc.id}/prices`)
    );
    const subQDetails = await getDocs(subQuery);
    subQDetails.docs.map((price) => {
      products[productDoc.id].prices = {
        priceId: price.id,
        ...price.data(),
      };
    });
  };
  setProducts(products);
};
```

Comment: Thank you Frank! That helped me to make the load Checkout work and to add the data to the cloudFirestore

Comment: Yes, I accepted the answer. I just can`t upvote yet. I need 15 points of reputation :D